# C++ Not Compiling In Atom

Tags: c++, compilation, atom-editor

I'm trying to write C++ in Atom, but when I compile nothing happens. I'm using gpp-compiler to compile, and I've got that configured, but when I try to compile, the window pops up says "Press any key to continue..." and it doesn't print anything else. I'm trying to print Hello World to test functionality, but it's also doing the same thing for old programs that definitely work, so I'm certain it's nothing wrong with my code. I get no errors or anything; it's behaving exactly as I would expect if I were successfully compiling something with no cout statements. I've googled around to see if I could find anything, but it's really hard to get results where there is no error message.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    cout << "Hello World";

    return 0;
}
```

I'm pretty sure gpp-compiler is configured correctly because I'm not getting the errors I was getting before it was configured correctly.

Comment: "when I try to compile, the window pops up says "Press any key to continue..." - Um... Is it when you try to *compile*? Or is it when you try to run the compiled code? Have you tried sending `endl` to `cout` after your string?

Comment: Gpp-compiler does "compile and run." Endl makes no difference.

Comment: I think your project is in it’s previous state when there was no print statement, try recompiling your project by pressing F5 or right click the file in tree view and choose compile and run. If problem still doesn’t get solved you might need to install MinGW and add it to your path

Comment: Try Dev-cpp, it’s a recommended c++ compiler

Comment: That is the way I am compiling. I have installed MinGW and it's added to my path. Dev-cpp stopped working for me; that's why I started using Atom. I downloaded it a couple years ago. Is there a new update? I looked around for one, thinking maybe it would have a patch that would solve my problem, but I couldn't find anything.